# Is it possible to list all the functions called after clicking the page with the use of Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, web-crawler

While writting spider,I always have to find out which function send the Http requset on the javascript page after I click it.

As there may be so many functions involved,I have to jump from one to another,guessing which is the key one.

while we run an incorrect program written in Python,the IDE will show the as the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/milu/PycharmProjects/spider/html prase.py", line 42, in <module>
    driver.page_source = html
AttributeError: can't set attribute

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anything similliar in Chrome Developer Tools to help me list all the functions called after I click on a page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open devtools and go to your network tab. Search the request that you want to investigate. One of the columns in the network table is the "Initiator column". There you'll find the script and line number of the javascript that fired the request. If you then hover over the initiator you get a full call stack.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.
I used to click on the  specific http request thus ignore the initiator